# TSQL limit records where count() =1 within HAVING clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

ok I have 3 tables which are linked on specified keys

```
account (accountnumber)
package (packageid, accountnumber)
hostdomain (packageid)
```

I need to get all accounts that only have 1 domain, here is my query so far, but it is returning all domains. What am I doing wrong ?

```
select 
    domainname,
    resellerAccountNumber,
    a.accountnumber,
    companyname,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    primaryemail,
    HomePhone
    workphone
FROM account a 
INNER JOIN Package p on p.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber
INNER JOIN hostdomain hd ON HD.packageId = p.packageID 
GROUP BY 
    domainname, reselleraccountnumber, a.accountnumber, companyname, 
    firstname,lastname,primaryemail, HomePhone,workphone, domainaliasId   
HAVING COUNT(domainname) =1 
    AND domainAliasID = 0 
    AND ResellerAccountNumber in ('','LNC','CFMXHOSTING')
```

Comment: Should  `AND domainAliasID = 0 AND ResellerAccountNumber in ('','LNC','CFMXHOSTING')` not be in the where clause instead of the having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aggregating by too many fields.  I think you want something like this:

```
select min(domainname) as domainname, resellerAccountNumber,
       a.accountnumber, companyname, firstname, lastname, primaryemail,
       HomePhone, workphone
FROM account a INNER JOIN
     Package p
     on p.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber INNER JOIN
     hostdomain hd ON HD.packageId = p.packageID 
GROUP BY reselleraccountnumber, a.accountnumber, companyname, firstname,
         lastname, primaryemail, HomePhone, workphone, domainaliasId   
HAVING COUNT(domainname) = 1 AND
       domainAliasID = 0 AND
       ResellerAccountNumber in ('','LNC','CFMXHOSTING');
```

I removed the `domainname` from the `group by` (and made associated changes).  I have no idea what to do about `domainaliasid`, because your question does not mention anything about filtering the data, only aggregating it.  You might want to remove it to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use only aggregate in HAVING clause:

```
WHERE
    domainAliasID = 0 
    AND ResellerAccountNumber in ('','LNC','CFMXHOSTING')
GROUP BY
    domainname, reselleraccountnumber, a.accountnumber,
    companyname,firstname,lastname,primaryemail, HomePhone,
    workphone, domainaliasId   
HAVING COUNT(domainname) = 1
```